# Why is my top-header on top of my navigation menu?

Tags: css, wordpress, header, header-files

I have created a custom top-header with CSS ID 'top-header'. But, it is showing up on top of my navigation menu instead of below it.

I have tried changing the top-header position from 'absolute' to 'fixed', as well as change the top pixels from 3px to 300px but nothing changed.

Edit: I am using Divi to build a website.

I input the following code to the bottom of the functions.php:

function custom_header ( $main_header ) {
        $custom_header .= do_shortcode('[et_pb_section global_module="38561"][/et_pb_section]');
    return $custom_header . $main_header;
}

add_filter( 'et_html_main_header', 'custom_header' );

Any suggestions?

[Photo of top-header on top of navigation menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71WXi.jpg)

```
    #main-header {
  box-shadow: 0 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
#main-header.et-fixed-header {
  box-shadow: 0 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) !important;
}
#top-header #et-info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
}
#et-info-phone:before, #et-info-email:before {
  margin-right: 8px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
#et-secondary-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
#et-secondary-menu a {
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media screen and (max-width : 600px) {
  #top-header #et-info {
    line-height: 1.5em;
  }
}



/*
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
NAVIGATION
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
*/

#main-header .nav li ul a {
  color: #000;
}
#main-header .nav li ul a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#top-menu .menu-item-has-children > a:first-child:after, #et-secondary-nav .menu-item-has-children > a:first-child:after {
  top: -2px;
}
li.sfly_social_media_menu_icon .fab {
  font-weight: 300;
}
#et_top_search {
  margin-top: 0;
}
#top-menu ul.sub-menu {
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 80px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
#top-menu ul.sub-menu li {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
#top-menu ul.sub-menu li a {
  width: 260px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
@media screen and (max-width : 980px) {
  .et_mobile_menu {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    box-shadow: 0px 25px 50px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    text-align: center;
  }
  .et_mobile_menu li a {
    color: #fff !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    padding: 15px 5%;
  }
  .et_mobile_menu li li {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .et_mobile_menu li li a {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 6px 5%;
  }
  .et_mobile_menu li li:last-child a {
    padding-bottom: 12px;
  }
  .et_mobile_menu li.sfly_social_media_menu_icon, .et_mobile_menu li.sfly_social_media_menu_icon a {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .et_mobile_menu li.sfly_social_media_menu_icon a {
    padding: 25px 10px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width : 600px) {
  .et_mobile_menu li.sfly_social_media_menu_icon a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Usually the header (& footer) of Wordpress pages are kept in seperate files which each page calls when opened. A couple of questions (to start) **1)** What is the name of the page you are writing your `top-header` code to? **2)** This same page that you're writing your code to, was it blank when you started or did it already have code that you're editing, and if so, then does the existing code begin with something like `<?php get_header(); ?>` ?

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: Thanks for your comments and sorry I didn't see these sooner! I made edits to the original question to answer some of these questions. Just to add, the name of the page that I am writing to is called "Home 2" and it started out blank and was built by importing sections from the Divi library.